# Android - android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException when acess Http client

Tags: android, web-services, http, thread-exceptions

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6343166/android-os-networkonmainthreadexception)

When I run the my android application, I got android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException, what is the reason for that.how do I fix It.this is my code

```
public class Login extends Activity {

private Button btnLogin;
private EditText txtusername;
private EditText txtPassword;
public String username;
public String password;
public boolean doLogin = false;
Intent intent;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);


    btnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnLogin);
    txtusername = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtuserName);
    txtPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.txtPassword);
    btnLogin.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View arg0) {

            username = txtusername.getText().toString();
            password = txtPassword.getText().toString();

            if (username.equals("") || password.equals("")) {

                AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this)
                        .create();
                alert.setMessage("Username or Password can not be Empty");
                alert.setButton("OK",
                        new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,
                                    int which) {
                            }
                        });

                alert.setIcon(R.drawable.loginlogo);
                alert.show();

            }

            else {

                HttpAsync httpasync = new HttpAsync();

                httpasync.execute(new String[] { "http://www.diskonbanget.com/bni/login/login.php" });

            }

        }

    });

}

private class HttpAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        String str = null;
        try {

            // Create a new HttpClient and Post Header
            HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(
                    "http://www.diskonbanget.com/bni/login/login.php");
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(
                    2);
            nameValuePairs
                    .add(new BasicNameValuePair("username", username));
            nameValuePairs
                    .add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));
            httppost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));

            // Execute HTTP Post Request

            HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);

            str = inputStreamToString(response.getEntity().getContent())
                    .toString();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            return str;
        }
        return str;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        String str = result;

        if (str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("false")) {

            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this)
                    .create();
            alert.setMessage("Please enter valid username & Password");
            alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });

            alert.setIcon(R.drawable.loginlogo);
            alert.show();

        }

        else if (str.toString().equalsIgnoreCase("null")) {
            AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this)
                    .create();
            alert.setMessage("Can not Connect to the server.please make sure your internet is Switch on  ");
            alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                }
            });
            alert.setIcon(R.drawable.loginlogo);
            alert.show();
        }

        else {

            intent = new Intent(Login.this, MainMenu.class);
            intent.putExtra("photo", str);
            intent.putExtra("username", str);   
            getApplicationContext().startActivity(intent);

        }

    }

}

private StringBuilder inputStreamToString(InputStream is) {
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder total = new StringBuilder();
    // Wrap a BufferedReader around the InputStream
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    // Read response until the end
    try {
        while ((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
            total.append(line);
        }
        return total;

    } catch (Exception e) {

        return null;
    }

}
```

please someone help me.android version3.2, try to run using XOOM2 emulator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I dont advise it though but you can use this for test. Refer to @imran khan for good practice.
Add this in your onCreate() method to bypass the checking.

```
if( Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9){
    StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitAll().build();

    StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy); 
}
```

Comment: I used this one.it's works fine.is there any problem if I use this method?

Comment: Well I have used it on my application which is in the market. There is no problem in the method, just it is disliked to load data from the internet using the main thread, and google add the StrictMode not long ago. A good practice to get data from the net is to use Asynch Task or service so you dont have to worry if the response from the server takes time.

Comment: Is this method to response time?. sry for my stupid question

Comment: No question is stupid if your intention is to seek knowledge. This method is just to bypass the process of checking if the internet request is done in a main thread or not. It has nothing to do with the request itself.

Comment: Now , I have question, previously I have used 3.2 as my target version. now I want to change it 2.2 . when I change to 2.2, above method is not allowed. it gives error. what should I do for avoid that one.please help me

Comment: Using AsynchTask will work for all versions

Comment: Yes StrictMode is not defined in 2.2. I added a condition. Please See my edit.That worked for me in all versions.

Comment: @Lazy :I am developing for 2.2 ,so I can not implement it in my code. because StrickMode methods doesn't declare.above edit version not allow in my 2.2 version,anyway thanks for your effort.

Comment: @Lahiru you are right! If you add this to your manifest file, all you have to do is to ignore the warnings;     <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />  . But like I said before using AsynchTask is better.

Comment: Not ignoring the warnings, you just disable the errors check if your are using eclipse.

Comment: i added to <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="15" /> my manifest file & still does not allow me to add above code

Comment: Hmm it is weird! Are you using Eclipse? Eclipse will show it as errors but you can disable the errors checking. It is working on my project, should be work with yours too.

Comment: I'm using eclipse.it doesn't allow me to disable the error. I'm very unlucky, i used async method, it also gives me error....:((

Comment: Okay start a new question with the asynchtask. It is not difficult.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that your login method makes an http connection in the ui thread, you should do it in a separate thread or use an [AsynchTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)..

You can pass the context to the task, and then:

```
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
   Intent showContent = new Intent(context, yourActivity.class);
   context.startActivity(showContent);
}
```

Comment: I got what you are saying also.Thanks for the answer

Comment: how can I call to start activity from my async thread class I tried in onPostExecute(String result) method but I give me android:os.NetWorkom Main Thread exception. if you can please help me

Comment: All your http calls must be done in doInBackground method, to start new activity (i updated my answer)

Comment: it also gives me a error. I edited my code above.please check it.give me a solution

Comment: what is the error and where..

Comment: Error place:else part at onPostExecute(String result) method  (when start to call new activity)  Error:android.util.AndroidRuntimeException: Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity  context requires the FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK flag. Is this really what you want?

Comment: remove getApplicationContext() add call it using startActivity(intent);

Comment: it doesn't work. I don't know what to do.............OsNetworkMainThread exception again